# python equivalent of gem serve

Tags: python, ruby, haml

Is there a python equivalent of the ruby gem serve?

About [serve](http://rubygems.org/gems/serve):

> Serve is a small Rack-based web server that makes it easy to serve ERB
>   or HAML from any directory. Serve is an ideal tool for building HTML
>   prototypes of Rails applications. Serve can also handle SASS, Textile,
>   and Markdown if the appropriate gems are installed.

I'm looking to utilize it to prototype mockups with html.